# Scientific Calculator without Memory or Exponents

Tags: calculator

My chemistry teacher requires us to use a scientific calculator that does not have memory, storage, or exponents, but I'm having trouble finding one. Does anyone know of a calculator that meets the requirements?

Also, sorry if this is the wrong exchange. This looks like the best place to ask a question about calculators, but I might be wrong. If there's a better place, let me know.

Edit:
My teacher approved an office calculator with memory. Turns out what my teacher put in the syllabus didn't match what she wanted. Hopefully that's the only inconsistency.

Comment: Have you tried asking them? I for one always have an example of an acceptable calculator for my students.

Comment: A Scientific calculator without exponents is not a Scientific calculator. What he requires is a simple desk calculator that can only do addition, subtraction, multiplication or division. Even those calculators do have a memory option. I have never heard about a chemistry teacher not allowing an exponent button on a calculator.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: There are some approved scientic calculators for local public exams, try to discuss this with your classmates and instructors.

Comment: @DMcMor I have tried emailing my teacher to ask about specific calculators, but I have just recently sent an email if they have any specific calculator in mind.

Comment: @NgChungTak I have tried emailing my teacher to ask about specific calculators, but I have just recently sent an email if they have any specific calculator in mind.

Comment: @imranfat In the syllabus that my teacher wrote, it states that I need a scientific calculator that neither has memory nor exponents.

Comment: @Moo I was able to find a calculator that has neither memory nor storage, but unfortunately the syllabus states that it needs to be a scientific calculator.

Comment: @Moo Yes, but without exponents or memory.

Comment: @Moo The reason they would not be approved is because they have exponents and memory, the two things that my calculator is not allowed to have. And I have emailed my instructor to ask if she has a specific calculator in mind, but I haven't heard back yet.

Comment: Well, I have not heard of such calculator. Good luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My teacher approved an office calculator with memory. Turns out what my teacher put in the syllabus didn't match what she wanted. Hopefully that's the only inconsistency.

Also, can someone mark this answer as community wiki? I don't have enough reputation to do it myself.